# NullPointerException en JSP usando SQL

Tags: java, sql, jsp

Intento hacer una aplicacion web muy simple, donde muestre el resultado de la ejecucion de un query de SQL.
Pero resulta en un NPE.
Aqui esta el JSP:

```html
<%-- 
    Document   : consultas
    Created on : 25-may-2017, 23:20:40
    Author     : Cliente
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="datos.Conexion"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Consultas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Consultas</h1>
        <a href="../index.jsp">Inicio</a>
        <p>Consultas Disponibles:</p>
        1. Conocer el nombre de todos los chóferes que tengan mas de 25 años.
        <%  
            Conexion c = new Conexion();
            c.conectar();
            ResultSet rs;
            String query = "SELECT Chofer.nombre,Chofer.aPaterno, Chofer.aMaterno" +
                            "FROM Chofer" +
                            "WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF (dd, fecha_nac, GETDATE())/365.25)>25";
                           
            rs = c.ejecutarConsulta(query);
            //TABLA HTML:
                out.write("<table style=\"width:100%\">");
                out.write("<tr>");
                    out.write("<th>Nombre</th>");
                    out.write("<th>Apellido Paterno</th>"); 
                    out.write("<th>Apellido Materno</th>");
                out.write("</tr>");
                
            while(rs.next()){
                out.write("<tr>");
                out.write("<td>"+rs.getString(1)+"</td>");
                out.write("<td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td>");
                out.write("<td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td>");
                out.write("</tr>");
            }
            out.write("</table>");
            
            rs.close();
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

y aqui el codigo en Java de la clase Conexion

```js
package datos;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Cliente
 */
public class Conexion {
    
    private Connection con;
    private Statement stmt;
    private ResultSet rs;
    
    public Conexion() {
        stmt = null;
        con = null;
        rs = null;
    }
    
    public void conectar() throws Exception {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-92RP7H8\\MSSQLSERVER:1433;"+
                                    "databaseName=Pumer;"+
                                    "user = sa;"+
                                    "password = PerroLuka;";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + " conectar =(");
        }
    }
    
    public void desconectar() throws SQLException {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + " desconectar =(");
        }
    }
    public ResultSet ejecutarConsulta(String consulta) throws Exception {
        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(consulta+";");
            return rs;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage() + " getMultas");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output de GlassFishServer

```html
Información:   SQLException: Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'FLOOR'. ejecutarConsultas
Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.jsp.Utilidades.consultas_jsp._jspService(consultas_jsp.java:91)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Si de algo sirve, estoy usando el IDE de NetBeans

Ya llevo mucho tiempo intentando entender el problema y necesito ayuda, gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea **91** de tu archivo `consultas_jsp.java`?

Comment: Me parece que consulta_jsp.java es la version compilada del jsp, estuve buscando donde esta guardada y no logro encontrarlas. El primer codigo que inclui pertenece a consultas.jsp

Comment: Lee esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados. Leyendo el log (**PISTA**: `SQLException: Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'FLOOR'. ejecutarConsultas`) y el código `} catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage() + " getMultas");
        }
        return null` la respuesta es trivial.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, si habia un error en el Query, sabia que iba a cabar siendo algo tan simple como eso :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

es fácil, mira tu consulta:

```
 Conexion c = new Conexion();
        c.conectar();
        ResultSet rs;
        String query = "SELECT Chofer.nombre,Chofer.aPaterno, Chofer.aMaterno" +
                        "FROM Chofer" +
                        "WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF (dd, fecha_nac, GETDATE())/365.25)>25";

        rs = c.ejecutarConsulta(query);
```

No has puesto espacio en la `select` entre *Chofer* y *WHERE*, así que la select te quedaría así como lo tienes actualmente:

```
Select Chofer.nombre, Chofer.aPaterno, Chofer.aMaternoFrom ChoferWHERE...
```

Acuérdate de añadir los espacios:

```
Conexion c = new Conexion();
            c.conectar();
            ResultSet rs;
            String query = "SELECT Chofer.nombre,Chofer.aPaterno, Chofer.aMaterno " +
                            "FROM Chofer " +
                            "WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF (dd, fecha_nac, GETDATE())/365.25)>25";

            rs = c.ejecutarConsulta(query);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, si se debia a un error en el query y no encontraba de que se trataba. Sabia que acabaria siendo algo simple como esto.